# How to implement "OR" logic instead of "AND" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am trying to modify a plugin so it can work with an "OR" logic within the groups and with an "AND" logic between groups. This is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/concypt/3cYNt/1/). My code looks like:

```
if ($.inArray(tag, itemTags) > -1) {
   return true;
}
```

If I have `["One","Two"]` in `tag` how to implement the OR logic for it.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you're trying to do?  Your question is way too brief to figure out your requirements.  Please provide examples of what the plugin is supposed to do.

Comment: I need to implement OR within groups and "And" between groups

Comment: @Imran - I don't think that repeating the question again can be considered "more detail".

Comment: @RobW, don't you mean `OR` `XOR` `XOR`?  :)

Comment: I assumed he meant that any elements matching any of the checkboxes in his demo fiddle should be shown.

Comment: @jfriend00 please see working example ... Its a filter for products. If user select two brands it need to show both products instead of one containing both colors. And for between groups it need to show one ... for example 
if I check 'black' AND 'hobo' then i should see black hobo (and nothing else)

if I check 'black' AND 'white' AND 'hobo' AND 'tote' then i should see a list of black and white hobo as well as all black and white tote (...and nothing else)

Comment: @Imran Your color filters don't do anything at the moment.

Comment: @jli yes I know ... I am working on it first I am struggling with first group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDGWN/1/) with what I think is the functionality you're after.

I just moved the logic around a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If the browsers you are targeting provide `array.filter`, you can do it like this:

```
var matchingTags = itemTags.filter(function(el) { 
                       return $.inArray(el, tag) > -1;
                   });
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/ksCzL/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Using ES5's [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method, this can be rather concise. There is [a shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility) for older browsers.

```
var tag = ["d", "b"],
    tagItems = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

var contains = tagItems.some(function(v) { // whether at least "d" or "b" is in `tagItems`
    return ~tag.indexOf(v);
});

if(contains) {
    // ...
```

This behaves as follows for this `tagItems`:

```
tag = ["d", "b"];        // contains === true (due to "d")
tag = ["foo", "x", "a"]; // contains === true (due to "a")
tag = ["bar"];           // contains === false (due to no matches)
```

You could also make a helper function for this:

```
$.inArrayMultiple = function(subset, arr) {
    return arr.some(function(v) {
        return ~subset.indexOf(v);
    });
};
```

And then you can use:

```
if($.inArrayMultiple(tag, itemTags)) {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A roundabout solution would be to wrap your `inArray` condition in a `$(array).each()` function that returns true if any of the iterated items is present in the array.

```
var result = function ()
{
    var r = false;
    $(tag).each(function()
    {
        if ($.inArray(this, itemTags) > -1) 
        {
           r = true;
        }
    });
    return r;
}
```